# Cannot connect to the mongodb at localhost:27017 Error:Network is unreachable

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to connect mongodb database(in ubuntu 16.04). I have already created a database. but i found :  Cannot connect to the mongodb at localhost:27017 Error:Network is unreachable.

Comment: `ps -ef | grep mongod` Will likely show that mongodb is in fact not running.

Comment: is it a command?

Comment: When you created the database, how were you connecting then? Are you connecting in the same way, or in a different way - in an application perhaps? I'm afraid that it's difficult to know what might be wrong, with the very little information you've given us.

Comment: I am using ubuntu 16.04. Firstly i have created a connection and all things are remained same, after this i am clicking on test then i am getting that error.

Answer (score 33):

To start a MongoDB service that is in stop mode, please follow those steps

1. Press `window key + R` to open `Run window`.
2. Then type `"services.msc"` to open `services window`.
3. Then select MongoDB server, right click on it, finally click on the `start` menu entry.

Answer (score 27):

Before, you must run

```
mongod
```

in command line.

Answer (score 18):

Before, you must run

- for windows

  ```
  mongod
  ```
- for linux or mac

  ```
  sudo mongod
  ```

on the command line.

Answer (score 3):

Try replacing localhost: with 127.0.0.1:

Instead of localhost:27017 write 127.0.0.1:27017

Comment: This is because the `mongosh` (MongoDB shell) itself uses `127.0.0.1` by default while connecting to the local MongoDB deployment. `C:\Users\Owner>mongosh` `Current Mongosh Log ID: 64535d74a111db96ce97700f` `Connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/`

Answer (score 1):

1.You should first copy your mongodb files into this route : "Users/YOURDIRECTORYNAME/"

2.After that you should create folder name "mongodb-data"

3.With terminal navigate to this route "Users/YOURDIRECTORYNAME/mongodb/bin"

4.Run this command :

mongod.exe --dbpath=/Users/YOURDIRECTORYNAME/mongodb-data

Now you can connect to your connection

Answer (score 0):

if you are using MAC OS just make sure you need to run

```
mongod
```

in your terminal

Answer (score -3):

- I was also facing this issue, Install mongodb and try after reconnecting localhost:27017.